# Y-Modem Implementation for .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a ready and free Y-Modem Implementation for .Net, preferrably in C#?

I found only C/C++ Solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [library for XModem](http://trackday.cc/b2evo/blog2.php/2007/08/02/net-xmodem) that you could adapt to use Y-Modem without much effort.